# If-else statement in DB2/400

Tags: sql, view, ibm-midrange

I am trying to run an SQL that contains  if-else statement in AS400 but it doesn't work. I am creating a View using i Series Navigator in order to run it.

```
SELECT IF FIELD1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'AAA' ELSE 'BBB' END IF
FROM LIB.TABLE1
```

The error I am getting is:

```
SQL State: 42601
Vendor Code: -199
Message: [SQL0199] Keyword IS not expected. Valid tokens: , FROM INTO. Cause . .
```

I tried without writing is null but instead

```
SELECT IF FIELD1 ='' THEN 'AAA' ELSE 'BBB' END IF
    FROM LIB.TABLE1
```

then I get the following error:

```
SQL State: 42601
Vendor Code: -104
Message: [SQL0104] Token = was not valid. Valid tokens: , FROM INTO. Cause . . . . . :   A syntax error was detected at token =.  Token = is not a
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `CASE` expression instead:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN FIELD1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'AAA' ELSE 'BBB' END 
FROM LIB.TABLE1;
```

`IF` is control-flow construct:

```
IF condition THEN 
   SELECT ...
ELSE 
   SELECT ...
END IF
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT ABC, DEF,
CASE WHEN (substring(GHI,1,4)) IS 'SOTH' THEN 'J' ELSE 'N' END as SOTH
WHERE ABC like 'ABC%'
GROUP BY ABC,DEF,GHI
```

Comment: You should explain a bit your solution, pointing out the relevant parts, and maybe providing some useful link... like... you know... the SO answers style.